# Booming Blade: Initial damage is what damage type?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers

> Hit: 1[W] + Intelligence modifier damage, and if the target is adjacent to you at the start of its next turn and moves away during that turn, it takes 1d6 + Constitution modifier thunder damage.

Is the initial damage untyped? Because whoever wrote the text seems to be making a distinction.

Also, if the target is moved away from me with forced movement, does that trigger the secondary damage?

Answer (score 4):

The initial damage is untyped. The additional damage is Thunder.

The second half your question is *only if said movement happens on their turn*. So if someone interrupts and forces them away from you, then yes. Else no.

Comment: So the initial damage roll would not, say, get a feat bonus from Thunder's Rumble?

Comment: @Admiralshlork nope.

Comment: @Admiralshlork Correct, because Thunder's Rumble says its bonus applies to "thunder damage rolls". Something like Raging Storm, on the other hand, *would* give its feat bonus to initial damage roll, since its bonus applies to "damage rolls when you use a power that has the ... Thunder keyword", and Booming Blade does indeed have the Thunder keyword.